# Which process made a file (or directory)?

Tags: linux, filesystems

A process on my computer keeps making a certain directory and I don't know which.

I could start my system with an strace on every single process somehow, I guess, but I'd rather not do that.

Is there a simple way of monitoring a directory and determining which process makes a change?

I'm aware of inotify. I know that it will notify you when there is a change. Will it also tell you which process made the change?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+auditing

Comment: A very superficial read of the inotify(7) man page indicates that the process making the change is not in the notification. However, perhaps some more in-depth investigation is required. I would say, auditing is the way to do.